# vb script Refreshall Error 424

Tags: vbscript, excel-2010

I have a VB Script that opens a spreadsheet, executes RefreshAll to update the sheet from external data, then does SaveAs a .CSV  I had the script working as it should, then moved job to run on another computer.  The job is running unattended through the Task Scheduler and now my error log shows ERROR 424 and the script no longer updates the spreadsheet, nor saves the .CSV. The script does run as it should on this machine interactively.  The Job is using my credentials to run unattended.  Anyone have any help on the Error 424???

Here is code snippet:

```
dim sLogFile, logFSO, objLogFile
sLogFile = "F:\Feed\FeedLog.log"

Set logFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogFile = logFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFile, 8, True)

Dim objExcel
Dim objWorkBook, objWorksheet
Set objExcel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("F:\Feed\FeedOlap.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")

objLogFile.WriteLine ("    " & DATE & " " & TIME & "    Starting Refresh")

objworkbook.Refreshall

    IF ERR THEN
        objLogFile.WriteLine "Error" & Err.Number
    End If

objLogFile.WriteLine ("    " & DATE & " " & TIME & "    Refresh Complete")

objExcel.DisplayAlerts=FALSE
objWorkBook.Save
objWorksheet.SaveAs "F:\Feed\FeedOlapCSV.csv", 6
objWorkBook.Close True
objExcel.Quit
Set objWorkBook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

objLogFile.WriteLine ("    " & DATE & " " & TIME & "    CSV Created")
```

Comment: Error 424 means [`Object required`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe43cc8d). Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: objworkbook.Refreshall

Comment: `objworkbook` seems to be good, otherwise the script should have already failed at the line `Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")`. What are the account settings of your scheduled task?

Comment: Run with Highest Priveleges, Run whether user is logged on or not, job uses a Domain User with Local Admin privileges on this box, job calls batch file that executes the script, Task Scheduler Service runs using local system account.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you are refreshing from external data, there must be a missing link to one of your external data files... You'd probably need to investigate every single external data link and make sure you can still get to it in your new location. (e.g. privileges to every location, mapped drives for your domain user, etc.)